# httpsの設定方法について

Tags: windows, centos, https

私が利用しているレンタルサーバー（CentOS）ですが、あるコンテンツにhttpsを付けることになりました。

他のWebサイトの情報によると、SSLサービスを利用してサーバー管理会社にhttpsにしてもらうよう依頼するとのことでした。
しかしながら、httpsを設定する方法を紹介するWebサイトもあり、どちらが通常のやり方なのか分かりません。

質問ですが、あるコンテンツにhttpsを付けるためにはサーバー管理会社に依頼するのが最善な方法なのでしょうか？
それとも、UNIXコマンドが入力でき、可能な限り自分でhttpsの設定を行った方が最もよいのでしょうか？

どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

【作業環境】
・Windows7Pro
・CentOS（レンタルサーバー）

Answer (score 2):

レンタルサーバの提供形態次第なので、なにが「通常」「最善」なのかもそれ次第です。

まずはレンタルサーバの提供会社のサポート窓口に相談してみてください。

Answer (score 2):

まず、「あるコンテンツ」が大雑把に言って「仕事」なのか「趣味」なのかで大きく変わってくると思います。
　また、レンタルサーバー会社でTLSやSSL設定サービスを行っているかも関係します。

以下に、私ならこうするというのを、簡単に場合分けしてみました。

1. とにかくさっさとhttpsでアクセスするようにしたい場合は、まずはレンタルサーバーの紹介ページで確認したり、管理会社に相談するのが一番いいと思います。
2. 自分で設定しなければいけない場合で「仕事」なら、有料のサイト証明書を購入する必要が出てくると思います。何故かなどは、証明書の意味や仕組みを意識して勉強してください。この場合、Webサーバー構築の参考書を本屋や図書館で探すのが早いと思います。
3. 「趣味」なら、OpenSSLなどで生成する、いわゆる「オレオレ証明書」を作ることとなると思います。趣味のサーバーでhttpsアクセス設定しているのもは、大抵このパターンだと思います。この場合の設定方法などは、Webでも沢山見つかると思います。なお、この場合でも、時間があるなら証明書の意味や仕組みを勉強するのがおすすめです。簡単な解説ならWebでも見つかると思います。

Comment: 「オレオレ証明書」、気に入りました。時間があるときに勉強してみます。
今回の場合は仕事で一貫で実施しますので、サーバー管理会社に問い合わせてみます。
ご丁寧な回答、どうもありがとうございます。

Comment: SSL証明書の取得は結構な費用がかかるためかつて個人で費用を掛けずにSSL/TLSを運用する場合は自前で認証局を建てて証明書を作る（これがいわゆるオレオレ証明書)のが一般的でしたが、今どきは無料で証明書を発行してくれるサービスもありますのでそれを使えばよいです。 https://www.startssl.com